# Server Power Management

Tags: laptop, power, power-management, ups

I am making a single ssh server, and unfortunately, my area suffers from frequent weather-related power outages. This is going to be a bit of a problem if I want to have a server running unless:

**a)** I add a UPS, and it runs something when there is no power (to notify me that the power is out)

**b)** I have some sort of other computer or setting that will automatically notify that "The server is down" when the ssh server has no power, and the ssh server will stop gracefully whilst in the middle of operation. However, this is not very effective in actually getting any work done.

**c)** It is a laptop that is always charging, so it will run even if the power is out, and it runs something when there is no power (see **(a)**). (this is a nice way to set up home servers, but it makes me cringe at the upgradability and cost)

It also will need to automatically restart after the power comes on in any case, be it the laptop battery that dies, the ups that dies, or the wall socket on its own.

This being the way things are, what is my best option, considering cost, quality, and overall effectiveness? Also, are there any other ways to do this that I should use instead?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way is just to use a UPS (most come with software that can notify you when the power dies these days, just make sure that is a feature when you are selecting one).  As for the auto-restart, that is a bios option in most computers (something like "reboot after power resume" in the bios setup pages).  Make sure you have your modem on the UPS too.

Comment: Many of these can be managed through the network too, worth buying for a "server"